# Get custom MSBuild task's output parameter from TFS build workflow

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, msbuild-task

I have a custom MSBuild task that implements an output property.  How can I retrieve the value of that property on the build server in build workflow activities that occur after the MSBuild activity has completed?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the property to a file and read it in your build activity. The name of the file should be passed to msbuild on the command line to reduce coupling between team build and msbuild